# Is there any package in python which lets me know what a specific word is: an object, a place or an action. Or is there any API

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

Is there any package in python which can be used to find whether a word is an object , a place or an action. Here i am talking about a single word not a sentence and also I dont need to POS tagging.

## Example

### Cake, Pen, Paper : object ;

### Classroom, outdoor, beach , mountain : place ;

### Hiking, adventure, swimming : Action

Answer (score 1):

Wordnet provides hypernyms.
I wrote a basic exemple to show how it can be used.
(you will have to do some fine-tuning if you want it to handle a larger variety of words)

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet

def getHypernyms(word):
    synsets = wordnet.synsets(word)

    while synsets:

        #print(synsets[0].hypernyms() )
        synsets = synsets[0].hypernyms()
        if not synsets:
            return('not found')
        lemma = synsets[0].lemmas()
        name = lemma[0].name() 
        if name in ['entity' , 'object']:
            return('object')
        if name in ['action' , 'activity']:
            return('action')
        if name in ['area' , 'geological_formation']:
            return('place')



l = ["cake", "pen", "paper", "hiking", "swimming", "adventure", "classroom", "outdoor", "mountain", "beach" ]
for a in l:
    print(a, "->", getHypernyms(a))

#cake -> object
#pen -> object
#paper -> object
#hiking -> action
#swimming -> action
#adventure -> action
#classroom -> place
#outdoor -> not found
#mountain -> place
#beach -> place
```